# Child UpdatePanel and parent UpdateProgress problem

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have a nested child and parent UpdatePanel. The problem is, when the child UpdatePanel is refreshed/posted, the UpdateProgress in parent fires up. How can I prevent this? The structure is like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
                    <ProgressTemplate></ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>

        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
                    <ProgressTemplate></ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress3" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel2">
                                    <ProgressTemplate></ProgressTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdateProgress>
            </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>

        </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When `UpdatePanel2` is posted, `UpdateProgress3` is not displayed but `UpdateProgress1` and `UpdateProgress2` are. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The [UpdateMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx) property of `UpdatePanel1` is not specified, so it defaults to `Always`, which means `UpdatePanel1` will be refreshed when any other `UpdatePanel` on the page performs a partial postback.

Try specifying `UpdateMode="Conditional"` in all your `UpdatePanels`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I've added UpdateMode="Conditional" to the UpdatePanel1 but it's still the same, UpdateProgress1 and 2 displayed, not 3..

Answer (score 1):

Seen here : http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/overview/UpdateProgressOverview.aspx

> If an UpdatePanel control is inside another update panel, a postback that originates inside the child panel causes any UpdateProgress controls associated with the child panel to be displayed. **It also displays any UpdateProgress controls associated with the parent panel.** If a postback originates from an immediate child control of the parent panel, only the UpdateProgress controls associated with the parent panel are displayed. This follows the logic for how postbacks are triggered.

So, I think you must hide the parent UpdateProgress clientside :

> You can programmatically control when an UpdateProgress control is displayed by using the JavaScript beginRequest and endRequest events of the PageRequestManager class. In the beginRequest event handler, display the DOM element that represents the UpdateProgress control. In the endRequest event handler, hide the element.